# White Screen Laravel App in Debian Server

Tags: laravel, server, debian

I have this Laravel App that works as an API for an iOS app that runs perfectly in localhost but when I migrated the app from local host to a Debian web server it throws me a white screen.

I don't have a domain, only ip Address.

Laravel App Document `/var/www/html/LaravelApp`

Software install:

```
apache2
mysql
php7.0
php5.6
```

Already tried:

```
$ sudo chown -R www-data /var/www/html/LaravelApp
$ sudo chmod -R gu+w storage
$ sudo chmod -R guo+w storage
$ sudo chmod -R gu+w bootstrap/cache
$ sudo chmod -R guo+w bootstrap/cache
```

[I also tried other other ways of changing permissions (I even gave 777 to the hole project)]

Also changing apache DocumentRoot to `/var/www/html/LaravelApp/public`

I tried entering a fake route and it doesn't show me not found like a laravel app it shows me the apache basic 404
[image: /fakeRoute]

I can access the directory tree and see al files, the white screen appears whenever I enter public.

Updates:
**I always restarted apache after every change**

PHP Error Log:

```
$ php --info | grep error

display_errors => Off => Off
display_startup_errors => Off => Off
error_append_string => no value => no value
error_log => no value => no value
error_prepend_string => no value => no value
error_reporting => 22527 => 22527
html_errors => Off => Off
ignore_repeated_errors => Off => Off
log_errors => On => On
log_errors_max_len => 1024 => 1024
track_errors => Off => Off
xmlrpc_error_number => 0 => 0
xmlrpc_errors => Off => Off
opcache.error_log => no value => no value
```

Access.log (of fake route):

```
192.168.65.254 - - [11/Apr/2018:16:11:31 -0500] "GET /GeneraAPI/public/fakeRoute HTTP/1.1" 404 521 "-" "Mozilla/5.$
192.168.65.254 - - [11/Apr/2018:16:25:24 -0500] "GET /GeneraAPI/public/fakeRoute HTTP/1.1" 404 521 "-" "Mozilla/5.$
192.168.65.254 - - [11/Apr/2018:16:25:25 -0500] "GET /GeneraAPI/public/fakeRoute HTTP/1.1" 404 521 "-" "Mozilla/5.$
```

Comment: Did you restart apache after changing the DocumentRoot?

Comment: What's in your PHP error log?

Comment: @ChrisForrence yes, actually after every change I always restarted apache

Comment: @Ohgodwhy sorry for my inexperience but where's the php error log?

Comment: I don't know how you have configured your php integration but if you're using it as a module then it would probably be in `/var/log/apache2` You can also determine the location by running `php --info | grep error ` from the CLI. If you've made no modifications, then the CLI error log and the Web error logs will use the same log file

Comment: Can you access with `http://your.domain/LaravelApp/public`?

Comment: yes, but it only shows me a white screen @Tpojka

Comment: What is in `storage/logs/laravel.log`? It will tell you application error (in case of any). You can delete contents of that file and make new request for readability.

Comment: What does your VirtualHost entry look like?

Comment: did you set the right permissions on folders/files?

Comment: @Tpojka storage/logs/laravel.log is empty and it doesn't record the errors.

Comment: Clear access and error log files in `/var/log/apache2` directory and make real (not fake one) request and pass back what shows there.

Comment: @ChrisForrence which one, /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf or /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Comment: @Tpojka a white screen again.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel App Document **/var/www/html/LaravelApp** should be **/var/www/html/LaravelApp/public**

These are the folders that need to have 777 permission

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/LaravelApp/storage/
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/LaravelApp/bootstrap/
```

Also make sure Apache has the url rewrite rule correctly.